# Check if module $ \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 +1)$ over $ \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is simple.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I know a simple module is one with no proper submodules, i.e $M$ only contains $0$ and itself. I do not know how to show this for rhe polynomial in question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general, if $ R $ is any commutative ring with a maximal ideal $ \mathfrak m $, then $ R/\mathfrak m $ is a simple $ R $-module. This follows since any $ R $-submodule of $ R/\mathfrak m $ would also be a $ R/\mathfrak m $-submodule of $ R/\mathfrak m $, i.e it would be an ideal of $ R/\mathfrak m $. Now, what are the ideals of a field?

Comment: The ideals of a field are (0) and (1)

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2 = -1$ in the quotient, you may assume that every element has the form $ax + b$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$.  If $a \neq 0$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2}{b^2 + a^2}\left(\frac{b}{a^2}-\frac{1}{a}x\right)(ax + b) &= \left(\frac{a^2}{b^2 + a^2}\right)\left( \frac{b}{a^2}ax + \frac{b^2}{a^2} -x^2 - \frac{b}{a}x \right) \\ &= \left(\frac{a^2}{b^2 + a^2}\right) \left( \frac{b^2}{a^2} + 1 \right) \\ &= 1.
\end{align*}
$$
If $a = 0$, then
$$
\frac{1}{b} b = 1.
$$
Once you can get $1$, you can get any other element.